# dynamic table in flask from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, flask, dynamic-tables

I have a pandas data frame with the following columns

```
Symbol, Rate, volume
```

There are 100 rows in this table. I would like to display it on a webpage (using flask) and give an option to sort for each column=> Symbol alphabetically, Rate and Volume numerically.

Can you give me some suggestions about the simplest way to do this? I am not very familiar with Javascript, but I am sure if you point an example code I will be able to integrate it

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dataframe using the [`to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) function adding a custom class. Setting the `index` argument to False will commit the dataframe's indices in the output:

Python:

```
df.to_html(classes=["sortable"], index=False) # produces a string with the HTML table
```

Write the table to de desired page after it is passed from the backend to the frontend using flask. Use [tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) to allow the columns to be sorted upon clicking on them:

JavaScript:

```
  $(".dataframe.sortable").tablesorter();
```

I have added a code snippet demonstrating this idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dataframe.sortable").tablesorter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" class="dataframe sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: left; cursor: pointer;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
      <th>Values</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>1200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>600</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```