# Render Pandas Dataframe in HTML via Jinja2Templates

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, jinja2, fastapi

I am trying to render a Pandas Dataframe in HTML and not seeing anything happening.  When I say "anything happening", I mean I would expect to at least see where the problem is occurring.

I have the below Python using FastAPI:

```
    from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

    templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

    df = query_api.query_data_frame(flux)
    render_df = df.to_html()

    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "data": render_df})
```

And it refers to the following template:

```
<h2>
    Below is the data you requested from {{device_id}}
</h2>

{{render_df}}
```

Note that I've verified there is a Dataframe assigned to `df`.  The resulting HTML is when viewing pagesource:

```
<h2>
    Below is the data you requested from 
</h2>
```

Comment: If you add a `print(render_df)` in your python file, do you see the correct HTML in the terminal?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67136314/dynamic-table-in-flask-from-pandas-dataframe/68144164#68144164